# Approximating the first moment of $h(x)$ where $x$ ~${\rm log\,normal}(\mu, \sigma)$

Tags: normal-distribution, monte-carlo, lognormal-distribution, approximation

What is the best way to approximate $E(h(X))$, where $X$ ~ Lognomal($\mu, \sigma$)?

So far, I can think of Monte Carlo Methods and Gaussian Hermite quadrature as below:
\begin{align}
E(h(X))  &=  \int_{0}^{\infty} h(x)  \frac 1 x \cdot \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi\,}} \exp\left( -\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dx  \\[8pt]
\end{align}
using a change of variable $y = ln(x)$:
\begin{align}
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(e^y)  \frac 1 {e^y} \cdot \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi\,}} \exp\left( -\frac{(y -\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) e^y dy  \\
 &=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(e^y)   \cdot \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi\,}} \exp\left( -\frac{(y -\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)dy 
\end{align}
having $h(e^y) = g(y)$
$$
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y)   \cdot \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi\,}} \exp\left( -\frac{(y -\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dy.
$$
Using the Gauss-Hermite quadrature from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature) in Wikipedia:
\begin{align}
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y)   \cdot \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi\,}} \exp\left( -\frac{(y -\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dy &\approx  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{i=1}^n w_i g(\sqrt{2} \sigma x_i + \mu)  \\
&=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{i=1}^n w_i h(e^{(\sqrt{2} \sigma x_i + \mu)}).
\end{align}
Is what I am doing here fine? Or this would produce approximation errors?

Comment: Minor comment about your question: When you do change of variables, the integration limits should also change, i.e., it should be from $0$ to $\infty$ instead of $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: The change of variable is  $y = ln(x)$, so the new variable  $-\infty <y < \infty$.

Comment: Since $h$ is not stipulated, *it doesn't matter what distribution you assume for $X.$* That's because, letting $F$ be the distribution function of $X$ (which is invertible) and letting $G$ be any other invertible continuous distribution function, $$h(X)=h(F^{-1}G(G^{-1}((F(X)))))=(h\circ F^{-1}\circ G)(Y)$$ where $Y$ has $G$ for its distribution and now $h\circ F^{-1}\circ G$ plays the role of $h.$  That makes this question too broad to be answerable.